# Error 'MotherBoard(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, float, java.lang.String)' in 'com.company.MotherBoard' cannot be applied to '()'

Tags: java, class

I've been trying to instantiate an object of a class inside of another class but it gives me the error described in the title.

As an example, here is what the code looks like:

```
package com.company;

public class Desktop {
    private String coolerType;

    public MotherBoard mb = new MotherBoard();

    public GraphicsCard gpu = new GraphicsCard();

    public String getCoolerType() {
        return coolerType;
    }

    public void setCoolerType(String coolerType) {
        if(!this.coolerType.isEmpty()) {
            this.coolerType = coolerType;
        }
    }

    public Desktop(String coolerType) {
        this.coolerType = coolerType;
    }
}
```

"MotherBoard" and "GraphicsCard" are classes in the project and I want to instantiate them in the "Desktop" class.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: MotherBoard constructor takes 4 arguments. You are trying to call it with 0

Comment: You have two options: 1. Create a constructor in the MotherBoard without parameters or call the correct constructor that needs 4 arguments as mentioned by @Michael.